# Send array to every template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I've built a simple content management system and I'm trying to build a dynamic navigation bar but the approach I've came up with is to keep sending an array of all the pages to the application template from each controller. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Instead of each controller you can place in ApplicationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amit Patel mentioned in the comments to your question, the better approach is to move the code you're referring to into the `ApplicationController`.

All controllers in your application extend the `ApplicationController` class. Any functionality you want to share amongst all controllers can be placed in this class.

As an example *(since you've provided no actual code)*, you might set this up as a `before_filter`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :build_pages_array

  # Your other ApplicationController code here...

    private

    def build_pages_array
      @pages = Page.all
    end
end
```

The before_filter will run for all actions in all controllers, effectively making `@pages` available to every template in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your `ApplicationHelper` (`app/helper/application_helper.rb`) module and you'll reach this method from your views:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_your_array
    # create your array here
  end
end
```

In your views:

```
<% get_your_array.each |item| -%>
  <%= item %>
<% end -%>
```